# Action items/icons not displaying on action bar in Android App

Tags: java, android, android-actionbar

I am trying to have a search action on my action bar. I have set an icon and have showAsAction set to always but it is still always displayed in the overflow menu. How can I make it display on the action bar itself? Thanks!

**Activity**

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    setTitle("Add");
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Settings",
                   Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return true;
    }
    if (id == R.id.action_search) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Search",
                   Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

}
```

**Menu XML file**

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:context="com.example.testtabs.MainActivity" >

<item
    android:id="@+id/action_settings"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:title="@string/action_settings"
    app:showAsAction="never"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_search"
    android:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_search"
    android:showAsAction="always"
    android:title="@string/title_search"/>

</menu>
```

[image: capture]

Answer (score 0):

Either remove

```
android:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
```

or delete your case statement for action_search in onOptionsItemSelected. Doing either of those will display the icon.

If you want to use SearchView the callback is handled differently than onOptionsItemSelected.

Documentation here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#ActionView

Answer (score 0):

Just change **app**:showAsAction instead of **android**:showAsAction

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="com.example.testtabs.MainActivity" >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="100"`enter code here`
        android:title="@string/action_settings"
        app:showAsAction="never"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_search"
        android:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_search"
        app:showAsAction="always"
        android:title="@string/title_search"/>

    </menu>
```